# Collision probability on uniformly random strings

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Suppose I have $m$ independent and uniformly distributed random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_m$, each with the same alphabet of size $a$.  Fix some constant $n$.  Sampling from this distribution, what is the probability that I obtain a word with $n$ collisions (that is to say, $n$ of the $m$ outcomes are the same)?  I'm hoping it's some simple function of $m,n$ and $a$, because naively counting seems to give a nasty expression.

Comment: How many collisions are in the word $xxyyy$?

Comment: 3: I mean there should be some letter appearing at least $n$ times.